# How to stop default CSS in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css

I have call 5 different CSS for Different theme & Login Page have set one extra css call 
but run time take some class of default css's so how can solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set other properties in the css files, which would override the default behaviour.

Unfortunately, there is no other method to prevent them from being applied. If there is no style at all, user's agent (browser) will apply its own style. So its a good approach to edit the CSS, in each file. Or atleast use JS to override them using jQuery or PURE JS as

```
document.getElementById("elementid").style.property = value;
```

Or using jQuery as:

```
$('selector').css('property', 'value');
```

This way, you can achieve this. But the best method would be to change the CSS values in the .css file.